# How get Environment Variables from lambda (nodejs aws-sdk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodes, aws-sdk-nodejs

We can set up Environment Variables in aws-lambda for example via AWS SAM:

```
Environment:
    Variables:
      TABLE_NAME: !Ref Table
```

How can I get this variables from current lambda via Node JS AWS-SDK?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Just as you would any environment variable from node

```
const tableName = process.env.TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: require('process') isn't necessary. Just process.env.TABLE_NAME will work as process.env is set globally in node.

Comment: Thanks point well made and I have updated the answer. Here is a reference in the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process

Answer (score 3):

I am just adding to the original answer to clarify the scope.To fetch any environment variable whether is defined by API or manually, you can use `process.env.VAR_NAME`

E.g. [image: Environment variable declaration in console]

You can fetch the above using

let env = process.env.ENV_NAME

To read about it , you can refer the doc at [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html)